# Create UIntPtr from hex literal

Tags: vb.net

When using this code:

```
NativeMethods.SetProcessWorkingSetSize(
    itemProcess.Handle,
    DirectCast(&HFFFFFFFFUI, UIntPtr),
    DirectCast(&HFFFFFFFFUI, UIntPtr))
```

I get the error:

> UInteger cannot be cast to System.UIntPtr

. Why is that? Similar code works in C#.

Comment: @minitech can someone at least give an explaination to &HFFFFFFFFUI value? I am trying to search over the net but can't really find it.

Comment: It is a Hex value; `&H` is VB notation while `0x` is C#.  You can use the Win Caluclator to view the decimal value of such things.  Paste the value into Programmer view then switch to standard.  The value is 0, but you cant assign that way because `UIntPtr` is a Type.  It would be like coding `Integer = 4`

Comment: `FFFFFFFF` is not 0, it is 4294967295, or 32-bit -1 or 32-bit `~0` (bitwise "not 0").

Comment: @Plutonix No it is not 0. It is `UInt32.MaxValue` or a `-1` for signed int. You are lucky that you didn't post it as an answer :)

Comment: yes....that didnt look right; I was trying to work out what he was trying to do assigning it to a type

Comment: @tmighty to clarify what? You want us to convert something which is already in VB to VB. BTW: What is `NativeMethods.SetProcessWorkingSetSize` How it is declared? Do you expect it to work in 64bit platforms?

Comment: you cant cast a value to `UInPtr` - they are structures.  you set the value when you create them: Looking at MSDN for `SetProcessWorkingSetSize` you need something like this: `Dim uip As UIntPtr(&HFFFFFFFFUI)`  (which is **not** zero) and pass it as the arg.   You might also look at PInvoke for this.

Comment: @Plutonix When I say Dim i1 As UIntPtr(&HFFFFFFFFUI), I get the error "Array boundaries may not be within type descriptors.".

Comment: sorry, you need to instance it: `Dim p1 As New UIntPtr(&HFFFFFFFFUI)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `UIntPtr` from a `UInteger`, use [its constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/629351k1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```vb
NativeMethods.SetProcessWorkingSetSize(
    itemProcess.Handle, New UIntPtr(&HFFFFFFFFUI), New UIntPtr(&HFFFFFFFFUI))
```